# Random ajax errors with jquery Post

Tags: ajax, facebook

I have a facebook application and I get random ajax errors sometimes and get stuck when doing ajax call.

This is the error:

```
POST https://www.dadada/handler.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET jquery.js:4
l.cors.a.crossDomain.send jquery.js:4
o.extend.ajax jquery.js:4
o.(anonymous function) jquery.js:4
nextLevel play.js:178
(anonymous function) play.js:118
o.event.dispatch jquery.js:3
r.handle
```

Any thoughts what could be?

Comment: Not sure if you changed it, but https://www.dadada/handler.php isn't a valid URL.

Comment: Try executing your code using Firefox, and for Chrome it could be an antivirus https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/117805?hl=en